# Node.js with Socket.io - Pairing all users connected

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to the MEAN stack and trying to build a web app with it.  With socket.io, I would like to randomly pair up all the users that are currently connected to the page.

My approach would be to use random integers in the range of the length of a list of all users connected, as indices of the randomly selected users in the array.

I know this is something that I can do to keep track of all clients/sockets connected:

```
io.sockets.on('connect', function(client) {
    clients.push(client); 

    client.on('disconnect', function() {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(client), 1);
    });
});
```

But would it have issues with scaling?  If so, what would be a better approach?  Please advise.

Comment: you could use socket.io rooms, but only two users?

Comment: okay it makes sense after pairing, but what about a scalable way of pairing the users?

Comment: you can't make an accurate prediction for something that it must be scalable you need at least a prototype to determinate the result.

You can try an hash with the all the socket ids as keys and the other pair as value, simple and fast without looping .. but first you must test it.